# Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysqli_driver::and()

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

```
$q_cat_beauty = $this->db->select('*')->from('ms_categories')->where('source_id', 1)->and('category_name', 'Oral Care')->get();
```

i am trying to fetch the category name from my table.

Comment: it shows me **Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysqli_driver::and()**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no   `and` keyword or method in CI. If you want where with and condition you again have to write `where`

```
$q_cat_beauty = $this->db->select('*')->from('ms_categories')
->where('source_id', 1)->where('category_name', 'Oral Care')->get();
```

or use array in where

```
$q_cat_beauty = $this->db->select('*')->from('ms_categories')
->where(array('source_id'=> 1,'category_name' => 'Oral Care'))->get();
```

Comment: what if i need to use IN condition in it..??? can it be like  '$q_cat_beauty = $this->db->select('*')->from('ms_categories')->where('source_id', 1)->and(category_id)->in(1,2,3);'

Comment: use `$this->db->where_in()` https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html

Comment: couldn't get you. can u please elaborate it, if u don't mind

Comment: does this work `$array = array(1,2,20);` `$q_cat_beauty = $this->db->select('*')->from('ms_categories')->where('source_id', 2)->where_in('category_id', $array)->get();`

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
 $q_cat_beauty =
 $this->db->where('source_id', 1)
->where('category_name', 'Oral Care')
->get('ms_categories')
->result_array();
```

The Query builder class dosnt support and()   so if you chain 2 where together like above it will represent the and you can keep chaining

https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html